# Java EE6 My goal is to make web applications!

Tags: jakarta-ee

I finished reading the Books "Headfirst - Java" and "Headfirst - Servlets and JSP". Because this topic (web applications) is so big and complicated, I would like to ask what I should learn next. Should i focus on Java EE 5 or Java EE 6. I know EE 6 is different use JSF+Facelets on other side EE 5 use JSP/Servlets what is more use JSF/Servlets or JSF/Facelets?

Comment: Go with EE6 and don't get discouraged by lack of answers. Your question is too vague. Next time come up with more specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just read those books, understand what they teach.
Then go on and expand on that knowledge.

Start learning with the latest release, always a good idea, unless your book tells you to use another (in which case you should use that unless you're familiar with any differences).
But don't expect to use that always. Most software out there that needs maintenance and development will be written using older technology and can not (or will not, which amounts to the same thing for you) be modified to use the newer technology.

JSF is the future for new development, but expect to use JSP and servlets a lot as well.
JSF being built on those two, it's good to know them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE6 pushes forward JSF but it doesn't mean you can't use [Servlets and JSP in EE6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_6_.28Dec_10.2C_2009.29). I'd personally recommend starting with pure servlets and JSPs because they are easier to set uo and understand, especially if you have PHP experience. Search the web for some tutorials that lead you through the creation of a simple web application to learn the basics and then expand it to learn more and more stuff or just download some [OSS java web app](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=java+web+application&fq%5b%5d=trove%3A198&fq%5b%5d=trove%3A87&fq%5b%5d=trove%3A11) and explore it.

Reading is good but practical experience is much more important :-)